# Retrieve ACL of ParseObject given objectId

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, acl

I'm doing a basic query. Due to the way my code is configured overall, it would be really convenient if I could just do a query on my Design class and then find out what the ACL of that design object is given its objectId. I am aware that the following code is incorrect, so perhaps treat it as pseudo code. Obviously, I can't retrieve the "ACL" from the "objectID" of the design. But is it possible to get the ACL from the Design class with a specific "objectID"?

```
public static boolean WhatIsDesignSecurityStatus(final String objectID) throws ParseException {

    // get the design
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Design");
    ParseObject design = query.get(objectID);

    // check to see if the current design ACL is "Public Read" only. If so, return state.
    if (design.get("ACL").equals("Public Read")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use getPublicReadAccess(); function....

Just check this [link](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseACL.html)

Reference [link](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-security-for-other-objects)