# Parse - Create static data on dashboard

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am doing an app for Android with Parse platform. I want to create a ummutable table on Data dashboard's section, a list of cities, for example.
The Users can join to that cities that I (and only me) previously created on my Parse developper account.
I think maybe my question is related with read/write permission on that table but i can't find a good solution.
Thanks (PD: sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

As of my understand ....

If u want to add data into parse.com( city names ), U have to add it by manually. And about read/write permissions in settings u can change r pragmatically for each user like

setPublicReadAccess();
setPublicWriteAccess();

Check the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33687821/5185201

Comment: What I want it's make the table with static data throw dashboard, without code. And then read it programatically in my app. I want to set public write acces, but in the dashboard

Comment: Just U have 2 add the data in that table .... Double click on the row, and add it.